# Android Layout java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

```
    package com.example.scripthelper;

    import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TableLayout;
    import android.widget.TableRow;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class AddLine extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";


    Button btnAdd;
    Button btnCancel;

    EditText camNumberText;
    EditText shotNumberText;
    EditText descriptionText;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_line);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        camNumberText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.camNumberText);
        shotNumberText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shotNumberText);
        descriptionText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);



    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainTableLayout);
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(camNumberText.getText().toString());
            LayoutParams marginsRight = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            marginsRight.setMargins(50, 100, 25, 100);
            Log.d(TAG, "Right margin 30");
            tv.setLayoutParams(marginsRight);
            TextView tv1 = new TextView (this);
            tv1.setText(descriptionText.getText().toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "Description text good");
            //View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, row);
            tl.addView(row);
            row.addView(rowLayout);
            rowLayout.addView(tv);
            //rowLayout.addView(tv1);
        case R.id.btnCancel:
            break;

        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_add_line, menu);
        return true;
    }

   }
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at com.example.scripthelper.AddLine.onClick(AddLine.java:64)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-10 15:01:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have just started android and was wondering why its causing this error. I was thinking it might have something to do with the view that is in the `activityMain.xml` and not in addLine.xml..

Thanks!

EDIT*
This is the line that causes the problem.
Line 64: "tl.addView(row);"

Comment: Where's AddLine.java line 64?

Comment: Something is set to null, what is AddLine.java:64 refering to? When does this happen? More details required here. The answer below may answer it though, but my crystal ball isn't up to deciphering what is wrong.

Comment: Line 64 is "tl.addView(row);" in the onClick method. it returns null beacause the view is in another xml document. How can i find views in other xmls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says, about `findViewById()`:

> Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view.

That means that you can get only the child views of the layout that you load with `setContentView();`
If you try to load a view from another layout, `findViewById()` returns `null`

From the doc:

> Returns:
>   The view that has the given id in the hierarchy or null

So if you try to get `R.id.mainTableLayout`, that as you said is in another activity, returns null

Answer (score 1):

Your `tl` is null.

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainTableLayout); //returns null
tl.addView(row); //throws NPE
```

[findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) can return null, check your `R.id.mainTableLayout`

Comment: R.id.mainTableLayout is in another activity, can that have anything to do with it?